# Change colour of comments in a server configuration file when opening from vim in putty

Tags: ssh, vim, putty, colors

The comments in apache server configuration file, when I open them in vim through putty, are dark blue in colour over a black background and somewhat difficult to read

[image]

Opening the file in vim in the actual server computer is much easier to read, with the comments showing up as a shade of cyan and keywords like ServerRoot showing up as cyan and bolded, so it is still easy to distinguish between the two.

Is it possible to change the colour of comments for vim when using it through putty? I would rather not change it's colour on the actual server computer itself. Is it possible to make putty display it in exactly the same colour that it appears in in the server computer itself?

Answer (score 1):

Vim's 'default' colour scheme has two modes – for terminals with light and dark backgrounds. Unfortunately it's unable to detect the background colour with PuTTY and remains in "light" mode by default, therefore selecting dark colours for the text itself.

Use `:set bg=dark` to switch it to brighter colours, including cyan for comments.

Also note that Vim (nor "the server") does not choose the exact colour values – it only chooses out of the "ANSI" 16-colour palette provided by the terminal. Some terminal emulators have a quite readable "dark blue", while others have it *very* dark. But most of them, including PuTTY, allow each colour to be adjusted.

In PuTTY, the 16-colour palette can be changed under *Window → Colors*, so you can copy the RGB values out of whatever terminal you use at the server itself. (Dark blue is "ANSI Blue" and bright cyan is "ANSI Cyan Bold".)

Finally, I would recommend trying out different Vim `:color` schemes entirely – cyan or not, the default one is still not great. Some colour schemes use the 256-colour mode which allows much nicer colour choices and *does* look the same in practically all terminals (assuming t_Co=256 is set within Vim).

Comment: Click the app icon (top-left corner of the window) – or Ctrl-right-click the window – and choose "Change settings". But I'm not sure whether this allows you to _save_ the settings for future use.

Comment: I just checked. It does not save settings for future use.

Comment: It will never _automatically_ save settings, you will have to do that through the _Session → Saved sessions_ page no matter how you're editing them.